# Unix select system call

Tags: c++, unix

For those who would like to help, or point me in the right direction. I have a program that reads in other programs and command line arguments like this:

```
./mainprogram ./prog1 5 ./prog2 9 ./prog3 4
```

Thus far I have it working for reading in the first program but when I try to read in 2 programs it does not work. I thought a second set of eyes might help.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int bytesread;
    int checkfd[((argc-1)/2)];
    int ready;
    int maxfd= 0;
    int programs= ((argc-1)/2);
    fd_set readset;


    typedef int pipe_t[2];
    pipe_t *mypipes =(pipe_t*)calloc(programs,sizeof(pipe_t));

    for(int k=0; k<= programs;k++){
        pipe(mypipes[k]);
        checkfd[k]=true;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=argc-1; i+2){
        pid_t childpid =fork();

        //child code
        if(childpid==0){

            dup2(mypipes[i][1],mypipes[i][1]);
            //for(int q=0; q<= programs;q++){
            // close(mypipes[q][0]);
            //  close(mypipes[q][1]);
            // }

            int a=execl(argv[i],argv[i],(char*)argv[i+1],(char *)NULL);
            if(a==-1){
                perror("The following error occurred at a");
                exit(1);

            }
        }
        //parent code
        else{

            int result;
            dup2(mypipes[i][0],mypipes[i][0]);

            for(int z=0; z<programs; z++){

                FD_ZERO(&readset);

                if(checkfd[z]){
                    FD_SET(mypipes[z][0],&readset);
                    if(mypipes[z][0] >= maxfd){
                        maxfd= mypipes[z][0]+1;
                    }

                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }

                ready=select(maxfd,&readset,NULL,NULL,NULL);

                if((ready==-1) && (errno== EINTR)){
                    continue;
                } 
                else if(ready== -1){
                    break;
                }


                for(int k=0; k<programs; k++){

                    if(FD_ISSET(mypipes[k][0], &readset)){

                        bytesread= read(mypipes[k][0], buf, BUFSIZE);

                        if(bytesread < 0){

                            close(mypipes[k][0]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }

    for(int q=0; q<= programs;q++){
        close(mypipes[q][0]);
        close(mypipes[q][1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is one of the programs I am reading in:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int cube(int);
    void process(int(*)(int),int);

    if (argc != 2){
        cerr << "Usage " << argv[0] << " number";
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    process(cube, n);
    return 0;
}

int cube(int n){
    return n*n*n;
}
void process( int(*f)(int), int n){
    sleep(f(3) % 4);
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++){
        int result = f(k);
        char buffer[1024];
        sprintf(buffer, "cube: %d\n", result);
        write(1,buffer, strlen(buffer));
        //write(1, &result, sizeof(int));
        // cout<<result<<endl;
        sleep(rand() %3);
    }
}
```

The rest are the same structure just with a different sequence. Ok the issue is that when I try to pass in two programs the first one that is passed through outputs the sequence it is supposed to but the second, third, forth etc. do not output.

Comment: Is it possible to debug down to a more minimal example? Also, can you clean up your code formatting so that it isn't so painful to read?

Comment: -1. "Does not work" is not a valid problem description. Also, voted to close as "too localized."

Comment: What exactly is the question? Have you read the http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut

Comment: One little question - A person that wishes to help you would go thoungh all that code? Would you?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

- `dup2(mypipes[i][1],mypipes[i][1]);` is a noop -- you want `dup2(mypipes[i][1],1);`
- all processes should close all the fds they are not using.  Each end of each pipe should end up being open with one fd in only one process, all other processes having closed it.  So each child should have the write end of one pipe and the parent should have the read end of the pipes and no write ends, and all the redundant fds should be closed.  Using FD_CLOEXEC can help a lot to make this simpler -- if EVERY fd EXCEPT fd 1 is CLOEXEC, the children will be clean after the exec.
- it looks like your select loop is inside your setup loop, so you'll start selecting when just the first child has started and will stop doing so after starting the last child.  The former is innocuous, the latter is a problem.  You probably want one loop to setup the children (foring and execing), and then a completely separate `while(1)` loop calling select.

Comment: thank you so much for your helpful response, I will try your suggestions and see where it gets me

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean to do `dup2(mypipes[i][1], 1);` instead of `dup2(mypipes[i][1],mypipes[i][1]);` to replace `stdout` for the child process?